# Can't get my code to stop

Tags: python

So i have been running this code for awhile but It just keeps on going. I dont know how to get it to stop and print out the "total number of minutes", "total number of steps", an the "Average step per minute."

```
minTot = 0
stepTot = 0
t = int(raw_input("Input the number of minutes (0 to exit): "))
if min == 0:
    print "No minutes input."
else:
    while min != 0:
        minTot = minTot + t
        stepRate = int(raw_input("Input the step rate: "))
        stepTot = stepTot + stepRate * t
        min = raw_input("Input the next number of minutes (0 to exit): ")
    print "Total number of minutes:", t
    print "Total number of steps:", stepTot
    # Average is rounded down.
    print " Average step rate per minute : ", minTot / stepTot
```

Comment: Hey your first input is set to **t** not min...Also what langauge is this?

Answer (score 3):

Once you've accepted `min` from `raw_input`, it's a string, so you need to convert it to an int.  In Python, `0` and `"0"` are different things, so you'll need to make sure they're both the same type, either by calling `str` on `0`, or calling `int` on `min`.

Ideally, you'd compare `min` to `"0"`, instead of awkwardly calling `str` on a static number in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

```
while min != 0:
    min = raw_input("Input the next number of minutes (0 to exit): ")
```

`raw_input` returns a string, which is never equal to the integer `0`. Wrap it in `int()`:

```
min = int(raw_input("Input the next number of minutes (0 to exit): "))
```

Also, it's best to avoid naming objects the same as built in functions, like `min`. Consider changing it to `minutes`. Otherwise you'll shadow the `min()` function, should you ever need it.

Answer (score 0):

The `raw_input()` function takes input as a string in python. There are multiple ways to get around this:

**Convert to an integer:**

```
>>> minutes = raw_input('Enter minutes: ')
Enter minutes: 0
>>> minutes
"0"
>>> if minutes.isdigit() == True:
...     minutes = int(minutes)
...
>>> minutes
0
>>>
```

This code takes the input as a string, and if the number is a digit (using str.isdigit()), then we convert to an integer using `int()`.

**Take in input as `int(raw_input())`

```
>>> minutes = int(raw_input('Enter minutes: '))
Enter minutes: 87
>>> minutes #Notice that the following is not surrounded by quotations
87
>>>
```

`int(raw_input())` takes in **only integers as input**. If you type in a string it will raise a `ValueError:...`

**Use `input()`:**

```
>>> minutes = input('Enter minutes: ')
Enter minutes:  
>>> minutes
0
>>> type(minutes)
<type 'int'>
>>>
```

`input()` only takes in defined variables, or items you can call in your shell and it will not raise an error:

```
>>> 'hello' #This works, so it should work in input() too
'hello'
>>> input('Enter a valid input: ')
Enter a valid input: 'hello'
'hello'
>>> hello #This doesn't work, so it shouldn't work in input() either
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
>>> input('Enter a valid input: ')
Enter a valid input: hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
>>>
```